# jQuery datepicker minDate/maxDate working on one page but not another

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I've got a single JavaScript file shared between two pages on my site. On both pages, I'm creating a jQuery datepicker as follows:

```
this.$('input[name=effectiveDate]').datepicker({
    minDate: new Date(1405836000000),
    maxDate: new Date(1437372000000)
});
```

On the first page, the start and end dates are restricted as expected. On the second page, the start and end dates are ignored for some reason (I can pick any date). This problem is not limited to a single browser either; I'm seeing the same behavior in Chrome, Firefox, and IE.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong here?

Comment: You must provide the related code of the pages too.

Comment: Maybe try making sure that the input tag on the second page matches your selector.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the simple comments by both @afzalex and @DeepThought on my original post, I was able to determine the problem. I'll post the solution in case it helps anyone else.

In short, my problem was that I was effectively calling jQuery.datepicker() twice on the same element.

On my second page, I had a separate JavaScript file that was creating a datepicker using a more general selector. Although the code I referenced above was indeed being executed, I discovered that the more general datepicker code was executing later (and this more general code was not executing on the first page at all).

The moral of the story: Make sure you're not creating two datepickers on the same element (especially before you post to Stack Overflow like a freakin' idiot)!